# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener, tnsnames, ora-12514

I am trying to connect to oracle 11g installed on Linux EL 5 and and getting the following error

```
SQL> connect sys/password@ud06 as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

my listener.ora under network/admin is as follows

```
LISTENER=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ud06)(PORT=1521))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc))))

SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11g)
      (SID_NAME=orcl))
    (SID_DESC=
      (SID_NAME=plsextproc)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11g)
      (PROGRAM=extproc)))
```

MY tnsnames.ora is as follows

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

UD06=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ud06)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

MY lsnrctl status shows as follows:

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ud06.us.server.com)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                17-FEB-2010 16:23:06
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 12 min. 33 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11g/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11g/log/diag/tnslsnr/ud06/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ud06.us.server.com)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc)))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "plsextproc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "plsextproc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: I encountered **ORA-12154** on a machine on which only **Oracle Client** was installed. My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26020374/1497596).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you ping ud06 successfully (as ud06, not ud06.us.server.com)?

What does the command

```
lsnrctl services
```

show?

EDIT:
It sounds to me like maybe the database instance name isn't actually "orcl"? What the lsnrctl services output tells me is that the "orcl" service, although defined in the listener.ora file, is not actually running.

Can you log on with a direct connection on the server? If so, what do you use as the ORACLE_SID environment variable value? Log in as the SYS user and issue the command:

ALTER SYSTEM REGISTER;

Then issue the lsnrctl services command again and see if an additional instance doesn't show up.

Also, as Alex points out, the tnsping command is reporting a fully qualified service name. Edit the sqlnet.ora file and set the NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN value to NULL if it has a value.

EDIT 2: Does tnsping ud06 *on the server* work? Or is my assumption that client and server are on different systems wrong?

Comment: yes i can ping just ud06.

Also when I do tnsping I get the following

C:\Documents and Settings\a.APPLICATIONS>tnsping ud06

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 17-FEB-2
010 23:09:16

Copyright (c) 1997, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ud06.us.server.com))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=19.148.21.230)(PORT=1521)))
OK (350 msec)

Comment: [oracle@ud06~]$ lsnrctl services
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 17-FEB-2010 23:13:01
Connecting to DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ud06)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "plsextproc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "plsextproc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service Handler(s):  "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
LOCAL SERVER The command completed successfully

Comment: It's reporting the <b>wrong</b> FQSN; based on the tnsnames.ora entry, wouldn't it expand to `orcl.us.server.com` if it tas tacking the default domain on?

Comment: Good point. We need more information about what's in the config files on both server and client.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this problem is very simple. Do not worry about the .ora files or any other configuration. Oracle does all these just perfect.

Only while connecting via command line, it gets confused with passwords that have a @ symbol in them.

> > Therefore while connecting through command line SQL, do not use a password with a '@' in it. Just use the web interface to create an account having a password without an '@' symbol in it.

That is!! Problem solved. I had been breaking my head for quite a few days, and now my problem is solved!!

Comment: Thank you. I was also struggling from 3 days and finally got it. I have removed @ from password

Answer (score 1):

The `SERVICE_NAME` in the `tnsping` output doesn't match the entry in `tnsnames.ora`; is that file from the Windows box or the Linux box? It looks like you don't have a local (Windows) `tnsnames.ora` entry for `u06` and it's guessing what the service name should be expanding it - I think that's what the reference to the hostname adapter means.

Answer (score 0):

I also run into ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified, and adding the user trying to connect to the oinstall group of oracle fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

first try whether the oracle instance is started :

for windows:

start->configuration panel-> administration touls->Services->ORACLESERVICEORCL(my instance by the way)->start

Answer (score 0):

Provide the connection string like this:

ServerName:port/ServiceName;User Name;Password

[image: Add connection image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error, try this code:

```
SQL> conn  hr/hr  @pdborcl;
```

and if you find same error, it means that you have a different pluggable database name.
Check the pluggable database name by just writing the following command in `sqlplus`

```
sql> SELECT  name,  con_id  FROM  v$pdbs;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using this steps.

First of all, this error occured , if you didn't install same directory or drive.

But the answer is here.

1. Login windows as a Adminstrator.
2. Go to Control Panel.
3. System Properties and click Enviroment
4. Find the OS variable and change name as a "TNS_ADMIN"
   [image]
5. And change the value as a "tnsnames's directory address"
   [image]
6. Restart the system.
7. Congrulations.